# While loop with fscanf

Tags: c, memory, malloc, scanf

```
int* data=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int i=0,tmp;
while(fscanf(m,"%d",&tmp)!=EOF)data[i++]=tmp;
```

Why it's working instead of this? :

```
int* data=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int i=0;
while(fscanf(m,"%d",data[i++])!=EOF);
```

Comment: Your while loop condition is incorrect. If `fscanf` fails (returns `0`), then `data[i]` will remain unassigned.

Comment: amongst other things, as indicated in the answers... always check the returned value from malloc (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.   In the C language, it is a bad idea (that can lead to subtle program bugs) to cast the returned value from malloc(and family).  Note: the returned value from malloc is a (void *) so it automatically becomes the correct type, (without any casting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primary: pass address `&`, not value.

```
// fscanf(m,"%d",data[i++])
fscanf(m,"%d", &data[i++])
```

Other:

- Check against 1, not `EOF`
- Test index limit
- Consider array index as type `size_t`.
- No need for casting the result of `malloc()`.
- Consider malloc style  `type *var = malloc(size * sizeof *var)`.

  ```
  int *data = malloc(size * sizeof *data);
  size_t i=0;
  while(i < size  &&  fscanf(m,"%d", &data[i++]) == 1);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the address:

```
while(fscanf(m,"%d",&data[i++])!=EOF);
```

And checking if `i < size` is also a good idea.